# Ticket report - Auto populate from other worksheets into specific form

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2016

Hello ladies and gentlemen, I'm quite a dummy in excel and programming in general and I have a question related to building a report:

I must present a ticket report of which tickets are opened, how many tickets from each customer, how many days they are opened and brief resume.

[image: Example sheet]

Column B: incident n#, needed

Column D: brief description, needed

Column E: status, need to extract everything that is not "work done" and "work done - unconfirmed"

Columns O and P: Need to extract the data, first 15 characters of each line that falls under "not work done" filter.

Now this is a single customer's file. I can extract these files which follow the same model but in different worksheets (voto.xlsx, jug.xlsx, kplm.xlsx and so on and so forth)

Is there a way to consolidate all of this information into a single datasheet that informs the name of the customer in the first column, then the number of the ticket, then the brief resume, then the date of Column O, then the date of Column P, all of this just by saving these exports with fixed names?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What method are you using to "extract" the data and from where are you extracting it? Is this from a database, exported from software, etc?  More info of how you are obtaining the data can help us help you. In the meantime, there are a number of questions on this site which discuss combining multiple sheets, so have a look around.

Comment: Ok, I'm extracting these sheets in xls from topdesk, pretty straight forward: Extract and it generates a xls file with pretty much 16 columns from which I only need 5, I checked multiple questions however they are "sums" of number values from each worksheet, in this case I would need to filter which tickets are not "work done".
One thing I forgot to mention: Column N has the customer name, I just blacked that out.
So I prettymuch need: Column N, Column B, Column D, Column E, Column O (first 15 chars), Column P (first 15 chars), all of that filtered by non  "work done" from 3 diff worksheets.

Comment: So the software limits you to only exporting one customer at a time?

Comment: Correct, each customer generates one worksheet, unable to export the consolidated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Consolidate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-from-multiple-worksheets-in-a-single-worksheet-e328e6e0-8c27-4a8b-9ca6-2098315e7d82) feature to ***"summarize and report results from data on separate worksheets, you can consolidate the data from each separate worksheet into one worksheet (or master worksheet)"***.

This feature is found in the Data Tools group on the Data tab.

[image]

Sounds like your data is formatted the same on each sheet, so you should be able to consolidate by position.

Comment: Right, so I have a consolidated sheet, thanks, now to build a report with Column O (first 15 chars), Column P (first 15 chars), is it possible to extract just these chars into another sheet?

Comment: So this answered this question? If so, mark it as such. We are only allowed one question per post. You will have to ask a new question for how to build your report.